# On top the X vs On top of the X

Tags: prepositions

Is it okay to skip `of` in the following statement:

> Android is built on top of the Linux.

Comment: No. I'd say it's ok to skip `the`, though.

Comment: @m.a.a. that's not only OK, it's mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip Of, the sentence would need to be modified such as

> Android is built atop Linux.

where atop means - on the top of.

The definite article 'the' is not needed in this sentence.

Comment: What I mean is is it fine to say "Android is built on top the Linux.
"?

Comment: Silap - Not correct.

Comment: I think the phrase **on top of** in the sentence *Android is built on top of Linux* means **in control of** [http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+top+of]. I doubt the accuracy of *atop* here.  *Atop* means *on or at the top of* as in *She sat atop a two-metre wall*; or *The castle sits atop a cliff*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya In control of doesn't apply here. Based on the source you quoted, 'Following closely on' is the closest in context i.e. Android is built using platform provided by Linux.

Comment: Using 'atop' is not idiomatic; it may be used in more poetic or archaic writing. This is not really a question for ELU, Bhoomika; answering such questions just invites more. ELL was introduced for the use of people getting to grips with more basic usages.